# How do you get the value of a file when the HTML5 Files API (FileList to be specific) is not available?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, fileapi, google-caja

Google Apps Script HTML Service ([Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/)) is not compatible with HTML5 APIs, including the Files API. Therefore, I'm incapable of calling the Files property from the input object.

An approach that circumvents this issue and allows for me to handle each individual uploaded file would be greatly appreciated as all the solutions I've found across the internet involve HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a way to do this, although this API is so old it has been removed from more modern browsers. Use FileReader whenever applicable.

http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

> With this new API, each input element (not only file input elements),
>   is given a property called files. This property is our gateway to
>   reading local files. When the type attribute of the input element
>   isn’t file, the value of the files property is null. On the other
>   hand, for input elements whose type attribute is file, the files
>   property is of type FileList and resembles a NodeList object returned
>   by, let’s say, document.getElementsByTagName(). You may access it as
>   if it were an Array and has the following properties and methods:
>
> ```
> length
> item(index)
> ```
>
> Each element in the files property is a File element that exposes the
>   following properties and methods:
>
> ```
> fileName
> fileSize
> getAsBinary()
> getAsText(encoding)
> getAsDataURL()
> ```
>
> Those two lists above are all there is to know about the API for
>   reading local files. There is nothing more about it. No security
>   restrictions, no special configurations.